# JPA query does not return result when one of field does not have value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, interface

I have following Interface

```
public interface SchemeInterface {
    public Long getId(); 
    public String getVibName(); 
    public String getTerritoryName(); 
    public String getAllIndiaDistributionTerritories();
    public String getChannels(); 
    public String getPayerName(); 
    public String getPayerCode(); 
    public String getPayerTerritory(); 
    public SchemeInputSheet getSchemeInputSheet(); 
    public SupportAddOffInr getSupportAddOffInr(); 
    public SupportAddOffPercent getSupportAddOffPercent(); 

}
```

SchemeInput entity is as follows where I have mapping @OneToOne of supportAddOffInr & supportAddOffPercent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scheme_input")
public class SchemeInput implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("schemeInput")
    private SchemeInputSheet schemeInputSheet;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("schemeInput")
    private SupportAddOffInr supportAddOffInr;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("schemeInput")
    private SupportAddOffPercent supportAddOffPercent;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And I'm trying a query like follows -

```
@Query("SELECT si.id as id, si.vibName as vibName, si.territoryName as territoryName, si.allIndiaDistributionTerritories as allIndiaDistributionTerritories, si.channels as channels, "+ 
        "si.payerName as payerName, si.payerCode as payerCode, si.payerTerritory as payerTerritory, si.schemeInputSheet as schemeInputSheet, si.supportAddOffInr as supportAddOffInr ,  si.supportAddOffPercent as supportAddOffPercent FROM SchemeInput si "
```

In database -
`getSupportAddOffInr` & `getSupportAddOffPercent` can be null

the problem is above query works (returns result) when there is value for both fields getSupportAddOffInr & getSupportAddOffPercent. If any of the field is null query does not map data to interface object although there is matching data in database.

Can someone help me out please? Have been stuck since last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA specification states that using the dot notation across a relationship forces an inner join, and inner joins filter out nulls. If you want to be able to fetch relationships that may be null, you'll need to define that you want the query to use a left outer join:

```
"SELECT si.id as id, si.vibName as vibName, si.territoryName as territoryName, si.allIndiaDistributionTerritories as allIndiaDistributionTerritories, si.channels as channels, "+ 
        "si.payerName as payerName, si.payerCode as payerCode, si.payerTerritory as payerTerritory, si.schemeInputSheet as schemeInputSheet, supportAddOffInr1 as supportAddOffInr ,  supportAddOffPercent1 as supportAddOffPercent FROM SchemeInput si LEFT OUTER JOIN si.supportAddOffInr supportAddOffInr1 LEFT OUTER JOIN si.supportAddOffPercent supportAddOffPercent1"
```

Comment: I have @OnetoOne mapping of fields `supportAddOffPercent ` &  `supportAddOffInr` with my entity `SchemeInput`  hence adding a join doesn't make sense I guess.

Comment: As it stands, you are performing a join using "si.supportAddOffPercent" in any query, so I don't quite understand why you'd state using a join doesn't make sense. Are you after the Id or something else from supportAddOffPercent? If the FK is in SchemeInput and you want to access it in queries without a join, the JPA specification requires a basic mapping to the column - some providers have other ways of allowing it without mapping it, but I don't know them in Hibernate. I can't guess at what else you are after though and you'd be better off forming another question with more details.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the `SchemeInput` details for more clarification. Kindly take  look.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you've added or what you are after. The issue is using "si.supportAddOffPercent" forces an inner join in your query - I'll update my answer to be more clear, but inner joins filter out nulls. You need to use a left outer join as shows in my query. Try it out.